# Is Allocating and freeing memory across module boundaries possible or safe outside Windows?

Tags: c, memory-management, ffi

Having seen https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060915-04/?p=29723 and having (I think) run into issues in the past where the wrong `free` function was used to free memory; I've exported functions from my C library to free pointers allocated by my library.

However, when writing bindings for various other languages, I find at times I cannot (without significantly increasing the complexity of the wrapper code) add nice-to-have things; like a `clone` method in Rust because it would have to allocate the memory backing the new pointers which means later on using the `free_*` function exported from my lib on those pointers might not match the allocator used in the rust project even if I use `malloc` from the libc crate.

Now, my project doesn't actually run on any platform other than macOS (it's a helper to use a macOS only API correctly), so I was wondering if on non-Windows platforms if the rule about `malloc` having to come from the same compilation unit as `free` is correct or if I can mix and match malloc and free so long as I'm linking to libc?

Comment: No, it's not safe, as they may use different allocators (besides different libc like jemalloc, tmalloc, etc)

Comment: You can mix and match as long as they use *the same libc*. The thing is that different DLLs can use different libcs - even by accident! This is opposite to Linux where they all use the same one and it's hard to make them use different ones.

Comment: @user253751 well, since this is explicitly about non-windows platforms there are no DLLs.

Comment: What the link calls the "wrapper" approach, I'd call it a "per object" create/destroy (e.g. what C++ does when doing `new/delete`). In certain cases, the caller does _not_ know how to cleanup an object. So, in most APIs, the wrappers are provided (e.g.): `struct obj { FILE *obj_xf; char *obj_buf; };  struct obj * objcreate(void) { struct obj *obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj)); obj->obj_buf = malloc(127); obj->obj_xf = fopen("obj.txt"); return obj; }  void objdestroy(struct obj *obj) { fclose(obj->obj_xf); free(obj->obj_buf); free(obj); }`

Comment: Well, even on Windows, if you compile everything with exactly the same compiler & compiler options, you *can* use `free()` etc. across module boundaries. The main issue on Windows is that due to various factors it's trivially easy to accidentally use different allocators in different modules, even when using the same compiler. On macOS/Linux you will *typically* use the same system-wide C library, and you will *typically* use the same allocator, so most of the time you'd be able to get away with not caring about this. But always be aware what assumptions you're relying on for this to work.